# only one record sql

Tags: sql, database, database-design, relational-database

When I have for example only one record for administrators (only one administrator) with `id` and `password`, is it necessary to create a table `administrator` or not? Why?

Comment: Without a lot more context, this question doesn't make a lot of sense.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing inherently wrong with a one record table.  It's a function of your design.  For example, an administrator is not a type of user so you wouldn't stick an administrator in the user's table.  But that's a design decision.